# Qt Creator has no kits that are suitable for CMake projects

Tags: windows, cmake, qt-creator

When I try to create a new CMake project, I get this message error. I have CMake installed, and when I click Configure, it gets me to the Kits tab, where I have Qt4 and Qt5, Qt5 is the default. But no matter what I select, the "Next" button is still disabled in the Wizard.

What do I need to do to select a kit?

[image]

Comment: It's my first time to see the real practice of Q&A-style knowledge sharing. I've seen it in only help page >o<

Comment: Oh, I have other such posts. Generally I do it when I wish someone had posted it and saved me a lot of time (and frustration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out **the message was misleading**, talking about Kits, and the Configure button was further misleading because it opened the Kit tab, when all I needed to do was set the path to the CMake executable in the CMake tab (Tools->Options->Build & Run->CMake).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since last answered but in current version one has to go to Tools->Options->Kits->CMake to do the above mentioned configuration.